# To show that a subset $D$ of $X$ is dense iff it is $\epsilon$-net for every $\epsilon>0$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

To show that a subset $D$ of $X$ is dense in X if and only if it is $\epsilon$-net for every $\epsilon>0$.

> Let $D$ be dense in $X$ and $y \in X$, then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $D$ such that $d(x_n ,y ) \to 0$. That is, $x_n \in B(y, \epsilon)$ for $n \geq N$. But then $y \in B(x_N, \epsilon)$. So $y$ lies in some $B(x,\epsilon)$, with $x \in D$.

Is the proof correct?

But how can I do the other part? Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

Definition of $\varepsilon$-net : In metric space $X$, a subset $B$
has $\varepsilon$-net $M_\varepsilon \subset X$ if for any $b\in B$ we have
$m\in M$ s.t. $$ d(m,b)<\varepsilon $$

(1) If $D$ is dense, then it is an $\varepsilon$-net for $X$ (as you said).

(2) If $D$ is an $\varepsilon$-net for $X$ and any $\varepsilon >0$,
to show that $D$ is dense, we must show that there exists a sequence
$x_n \in D$ for some fixed $x\in X$ s.t. $$ d(x_n,x)\rightarrow 0$$

If $\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then since $D$ is
 $\varepsilon_n$-net, there exists $x_n\in D$ s.t. $$ d(x_n,x)<
 \frac{1}{n} $$ Clearly $x_n \rightarrow x$. So $D$ is dense.