# $\epsilon$-net for dense subset of $X$ implies $\epsilon$-net for $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with dense subset $Y$. If $A_\epsilon$ is an $\epsilon$-net for $Y$, is it the case that $A_\epsilon$ is an $\epsilon$-net for $X$?

My approach: Since $Y$ is dense in $X$, for all $x \in X$ and $\delta > 0$, there exists $y \in Y$ such that $d(x,y) < \delta$. Moreover, since $A_\epsilon$ is an $\epsilon$-net for $Y$, for all $y\in Y$ there exists $a \in A_\epsilon$ such that $d(y,a) < \epsilon$. Using the triangle inequality, these two distance measures imply that for all $x \in X$ and $\delta > 0$, there exists $a \in A_\epsilon$ such that $d(x,a) < \epsilon + \delta$. Thus, $A_\epsilon$ is an $(\epsilon + \delta)$-net for $X$ for every $\delta > 0$. But I don't see how to conclude that it is an $\epsilon$-net for $X$.

Comment: Can you check your definition of an $\varepsilon$-net? The inequality is large in the one to be found in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set

Comment: The definition I am given is simply: $A_\epsilon$ is an $\epsilon$-net for a set $Y$ iff for all $y \in Y$ there exists $a \in A_\epsilon$ such that $d(a,y) < \epsilon$. This is the same definition, for example, in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190699/to-show-that-a-subset-d-of-x-is-dense-iff-it-is-epsilon-net-for-every-e?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take as definition of an $\varepsilon$-net,

*$_{\varepsilon}$ is an $\varepsilon$-net for a set $$ iff for all $ \in $ there exists $ \in _{\varepsilon}$ such that $(,)<\varepsilon$*

then the result you are trying to prove is wrong.
Here is a counter-example.
$$\
X = [0,1], \quad Y = (0,1], \quad A_\varepsilon = [\varepsilon, 1].
$$
All points of $Y$ are at distance stricly less than $\varepsilon$ of $A_\varepsilon$ but $0$ is not at distance stricly less than $\varepsilon$ of $A_\varepsilon$.

If you take instead the wikipedia definition of an $\varepsilon$-net, then the result is true.